# How to create docker image for postgis that will enable extension at build time or before container fully running?

Tags: postgresql, docker, sh

What I mean is that I want to create a docker image for postgis that will be completely usable right after build. So that if user runs

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_USER=user somepostgis
```

the user database would be created and extensions **already installed**?

The official postgres image can't be used for that AFAIK.

Basically need to write script and tell that it would be entrypoint. This script should create database and create extensions with porstgres server running on different port and then restart it on port 5432.

But I don't know sh enough and docker to do that. Right now it's saying that there is no pg_ctl command

If you want to help you can [fork](https://github.com/purpleP/docker-postgis)

```
    FROM ubuntu:15.04

#ENV RELEASE_NAME lsb_release -sc
#RUN apt-get update && apt-get install wget
#RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt ${RELEASE_NAME}-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
#RUN cat /etc/apt/sources.list
#RUN wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
           postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1 \
       curl \
    && curl -o /usr/local/bin/gosu -SL "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.2/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture)" \
    && curl -o /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc -SL "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.2/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture).asc" \
    && gpg --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \
    && rm /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove curl

RUN mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN ls -l /docker-entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 5432
CMD ["postgres"]
```

So I'm trying to do somethink like that, but it doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash

${POSTGRES_DB:=$POSTGRES_USER}

gosu postgres pg_ctl start -w -D ${PGDATA} -0 "-p 5433"
gosu postgres createuser ${POSTGRES_USER}
gosu postgres createdb ${POSTGRES_DB} -s -E UTF8
gosu postgres psql -d ${POSTGRES_DB} -c "create extension if not exists postgis;"
gosu postgres psql -d ${POSTGRES_DB} -c "create extension if not exists postgis_topology;"

pg_ctl -w  restart
```